# Lotus Notes custom search

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I am very new to lotus notes.  This will all be done on the client.  I need to write a custom search that will search a particular form.  This an example of the fields:

FormName = MyForm1
database fields are called Name1, Name2, Name3
datasbase fields are department1, deparment2, department3, department 4.

The search form will only have 2 fields.  Name and Department.  I need the following to happen, The name search field needs to seach all 3 name fields, the department field needs to search all 4 department fields.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on exactly how fuzzy you need your search to be.  Are you searching for an exact match, or for a partial match in those fields?

Assuming the exact match, you just need a formula that looks in the multiple name fields, and multiple department fields for a match.  Let's call the search query fields NameQuery and DepartmentQuery.  Then you could construct this formula which would return true if the value in NameQuery is found within one of the name fields, and the value in DepartmentQuery is found in one of the department fields.

```
@IsMember(NameQuery; Name1:Name2:Name3) & @IsMember(DepartmentQuery; Department1:Department2:Department3:Department4);
```

If instead you need to search for a partial match, you could use the @LIKE formula.  First, concatenate the name and department field values into a single string using @IMPLODE.  You can then do a wildcard match.  This isn't very efficient, mind you, so if you're working on tens of thousands of documents you might want to find a better solution.

```
AllNameItems := @Implode(Name1:Name2:Name3; " ");
AllDepartmentItems := @Implode(Department1:Department2:Department3:Department4; " ");
@Like(AllNameItems; "%" + NameQuery + "%") & @Like(AllDepartmentItems; "%" + DepartmentQuery + "%");
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. So I would create a form and add the 2 feilds. And then create a view that would display the search results? If that, How do I connect the form to the view?

Comment: Ahh, now I see what you're trying to do.  First, you might want to update your question to better describe your goals.  What you are trying to do is a complicated thing in Lotus Notes.  Views selection formulas are intended to be static, but you can update them as shown here:  http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256DA400496CF2.  Using that technique you could create a form with those 2 fields in it, and when the user clicks "Search", your code could update the view's selection formula.  It's not elegant, and note that it would affect all users viewing that view.

Answer (score 0):

Mike -- 
The built-in search will work fine for you, no doubt!

Here are the steps...
- Build your new form (ie, "MyForm" ) to hold your data;
- Build your view, to display your data as columns;
- Set your view's "Form Formula" to "MyForm" (with quotes) 
- Make sure the "search bar", is enabled, for the view;
- Enter the values to search for;
- The results are displayed, nicely!

That should help...